# Убрать обводку у кнопки

Tags: html, bootstrap

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
```

Есть такая кнопка с крестиком, при нажатии на неё она обводится в черную рамочку, и так с каждой кнопкой. Как можно это убрать?

[image: Кнопка]

Comment: @Eric7777777 я использовал bootstrap 4 версии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойство `outline` задает внешнюю границу вокруг элементов.

Можно сделать через html для конкретного элемента

```
<button type="button" class="close" style="outline: 0 !important;"> data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
```

---

Само же свойство находится в стилях - обычно это `styles.css`

```
button:focus {
  outline: 1px dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
}
```

Вы можете убрать весь блок `button:focus` или же дописать отдельный для `button.close`

```
button.close:focus {
  outline: 0 !important;
}
```